# Apache rules overriden by others

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, configuration

I've blocked .htaccess files in httpd.conf file by:

    Require all denied

My httpd.conf:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ~ "^\.?ht(access|passwd)(\.dist)?">
    Require all denied
</Files>

IncludeOptional sites/*.conf
```

Here is my virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/site/

        <Location />
            AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/passwd
            AuthName "ADMIN AREA"
            AuthType Basic
            require valid-user
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from 10.0.0.0/8
            satisfy any
        </Location>


        <Directory /var/www/site/>
                Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
                AllowOverride all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Now, when I use directive location to allow access only for certain IP addresses or using login and password, this addresses can access .htaccess file. How can I resolve this problem? The .htaccess cannot be viewed by anyone.

Comment: It should be "^\.?ht(access|passwd)|(\.dist)?"

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing old and new directives, which can have unintendended consequences. In particular `mod_access_compat` will be used to handle things like `Order allow,deny`, and will take precedence over `mod_authz_host` for the new directives. See [upgrading to 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html#run-time).